# Laravel is it safe to use {!!nl2br(e())!!} in blade

Tags: laravel, xss

In order to output text in Laravel blade templates with new lines I use this:

```
{!! nl2br(e($prodData->text))!!}
```

I do not do not sanetize the data when I insert it, I just trim it to only allow two new lines in a row like this:

```
public function setDescriptionAttribute($description)
  {
      $this->attributes['description'] = preg_replace('~(\R{2})\R+~', '$1', $description);
  }
```

But now I am worried that `{!!nl2br(e())!!}` can cause xss injections so is it safe to use?

Comment: _"I do not do not sanitize the data when I insert it"_ - in order to avoid serious problems, you need to do exactly that. Sanitize your input before storing it in the DB. Also using double exclamation marks ({{ !! $test !! }}) will not escape data. Check this out for some tips on how to sanitize, there's many approaches tho: https://medium.com/@melihovv/how-to-sanitize-input-data-in-declarative-manner-in-laravel-e4486068f751

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Comment: You could add strip_tags on the content when you save the data, that might do some extra security on top of nl2br(e()). You could google XSS cheat sheet and try paste everything into your application, check if some of them go through.

Answer (score 5):

If `e()` is secure, then `{!! nl2br(e()) !!}` is secure (["safety" vs. "security"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58633)).

`{{ $foo }}` is equivalent to `{!! e($foo) !!}`. So `{!! nl2br(e()) !!}` is the right approach for your situation.

Regarding @Loek's answer: `e()` depends on the security of `htmlspecialchars()`. If there would by a flaw in `htmlspecialchars()`, basically every PHP website would have a *huge* problem.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, **no**.

There is only one rule when handling user input: **never** trust user input.

Ofcourse it's up to you to evaluate the risk, but by definition it is not safe. In the 2017 version of OWASP Top 10 web vulnerabilities, what you're doing is ranked 7th: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A7-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for your requirement. Laravel 5.4 + version

```
{!! nl2br(e($onlineSetting->instruction)) !!}
```